# Examples of Physical Applications ofthe theory of Principal $G$-bundles

Tags: principal-bundles, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

*Let $(P,M,\pi)$ be a principal $G$-bundle, $\omega\in \mathbf \Omega^1(M,\mathfrak g)$ be a connection 1-form and $\Omega \in \mathbf \Omega^2(M,\mathfrak g)$ be its curvature 2-form, where $\mathfrak g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$. Let $\rho:G\to GL(F)$ be a Lie group representation over a finite dimensional vector space $F$ and denote by $(P\times_\rho F,M,\pi')$ the associated principal $G$-bundle by the representation $\rho$.
The connection 1-form $\omega$ defines a covariant derivative $\nabla^\omega$ in the vector bundle $(P\times_\rho F,M,\pi')$.*

Someone tolds me that this machinery is the underlying geometric setting for many Physical Theories (such as Classical Electromagnetism, Quantum Electrodynamics, etc):

(1) the elements of *structural group* $G$ represents all of the possible *inner structure* of a physical system (for example, the point charge in the $U(1)$-classical magnetic field)

(2) The sections  of the associated vector bundle $P\times_\rho F$ can be viewed as wave functions $\psi:M\to F$ for the system (for example, the wave function $\psi:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb C$ of a classical charged particle)

(3) And the covariant derivative $\nabla^\omega$ is commonly used for define a suitable evolution equation for the wave function (for example, the Schrödinger equation for the classical EM field)

I was wondering if there exits notes/references/articles in which I can find other physical examples from this geometric point of view (Quantum Chromodynamics, Quantum Electrodynamics,  General Relativity, etc).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The book "Mathematical Gauge Theory" by Mark Hamilton.

Comment: Also the book by Bleecker on gauge theory and variational principles might be suitable.

Comment: Thanks! These book are what I was looking for

Comment: Let me add the second volume of "Differential Geomtry and Mathematical Physics" by Rudolph/Schmidt, the lecture notes by C. Bär on gauge theory you can find online as well as the two books on topology and gauge theory by Naber.